# Error in react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css Module parse failed .Toastify__toast-container { | React SSR

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-style-loader, react-ssr

i am getting error when i use  Error in react-toastify npm module and server side rendering.  toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0) You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type. |

```
Error:

 .Toastify__toast-container { | z-index: 9999; | position: fixed;

ModuleParseError: Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| .Toastify__toast-container {
| z-index: 9999;
| position: fixed;
```

Answer (score 1):

when server side rendering we should config style loader on both server-side and client side like

```
server-side webpack js Example
webpack.server.config.js or  webpack.prod.config.js
client-side js
webpack.client.config.js or  webpack.client.config.js
```

or we can create base webpack config and we can merge it in client and server side

```
** OR ****
webpack.base.config.js
```

i included my config in both  webpack.server.config.js /  webpack.prod.config.js and webpack.client.config.js / webpack.client.config.js

```
npm install sass-loader style-loader css-loader import-glob-loader
```

and my final

```
webpack.base.config.js

module: {
rules: [

  {
    test: /\.s?css$/,
    exclude: [resolvePath('../src/styles')],
    use: [
      {
        loader: 'css-loader',
        options: {
          localsConvention: 'camelCase',
          modules: true
        }
      },
      'sass-loader',
      'import-glob-loader'
    ]
  },
  { 
    test: /\.css$/,
    use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'] 
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding the below to the tsx file before you import the Toastify css seems to have worked for me. I will update if I find that this does not work, but so far it compiled.

```
require.extensions['.scss'] = () => {
  return;
};
require.extensions['.css'] = () => {
  return;
};
```

I found this solution [here](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/1754).